# How to get file and extension with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an upload of images that allows up images in jpg, png and gif.
It automatically renames the image to the user name that is logged.

This image will go to the background of the site that user.
So far so good, but the question is:
How do I know what length you climbed the image?

---

**How to Work:**

I climb a file with the name "AULA01-342.jpg" with the User "VITOR", it will rename the image to "vitor.jpg"

but i need to get that file there in the frontend of the site.
As if there in the frontend i know if the file is .jpg, .gif or .png?

Here are the codes:

How do I detect the file extension that is there in the folder?

**FORM:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo "cores.php?acao=updatecolors&amp;id=$id" ;?>" method="post">

  <input type="file" class="file-input" name="userImgBody" id="userImgBody"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success span12" value="atualizar" name="atualizar">
?>
```

**ACTION: UPDATECOLORS**

```
if($startaction == 1){
    if($acao == "updatecolors"){
        $id=$_GET["id"];
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE vms_cores SET 
        c.userImgBody='$userImgBody', 

        WHERE c.id='u.id'");

        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["userImgBody"]["name"]);

        $extension = end($temp);
        $newfilename = $usuario .".".$extension;
        if ((($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["size"] < 1097152)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["userImgBody"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["userImgBody"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["userImgBody"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["userImgBody"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["userImgBody"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("../_arquivos/upload/bgs/" . $_FILES["userImgBody"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["userImgBody"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userImgBody"]["tmp_name"],
              "../_arquivos/upload/bgs/" . $newfilename);
              echo "Stored in: " . "../_arquivos/upload/bgs/" .$newfilename;
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          } 


    }
}
```

**FRONT END**

```
// Get Subdomain
$urlExplode = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if (count($urlExplode) > 2 && $urlExplode[0] !== 'www') {
    $subdomain = $urlExplode[0];    
//  echo $subdomain;
}


// variable "usuario" == variable "subdomain"
$usuario = $subdomain;


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM vms_textos t INNER JOIN vms_users u ON u.id = t.id left outer JOIN vms_cores c ON u.id = c.id where u.usuario='$usuario'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
     // TODO: better error handling 
    }
else {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Tabela Textos
$userKeywords = $row['userKeywords'];
$userDesc = $row['userDesc'];
$userTitleSite = $row['userTitleSite'];
$userTelefoneSite = $row['userTelefoneSite'];
$userTextSobre = $row['userTextSobre'];
$userTextContatos = $row['userTextContatos'];
$userTextMaisInfos = $row['userTextMaisInfos'];

// Tabela Cores
$userImgBody = $row['userImgBody'];
}







<body>

<style>
body{
 background-image: url('http://arquivos.minisite.net.br/upload/bgs/<?php $usuario;?>');
}
</style>
```

The end result is:

```
background-image: url('http://arquivos.minisite.net.br/upload/bgs/vitor');
```

When it should be:

```
background-image: url('http://arquivos.minisite.net.br/upload/bgs/vitor.png');
```

or

```
background-image: url('http://arquivos.minisite.net.br/upload/bgs/vitor.jpg');
```

or

```
background-image: url('http://arquivos.minisite.net.br/upload/bgs/vitor.gif');
```

Depending on the type of image i did the upload...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You have several questions here. Do you want to get file extension, or the length of image? I see you have already obtained the file extension in your codes.

Comment: Actually I need or get the whole file path example:
http://www.site.com/image.jpg

and then only the file extension that is on the server with a given name.
being. jpg,. gif or. png

Comment: `pathinfo()` already serves your needs, as suggested by the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Where do i insert this script?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

This way you can get the name and the extension of your file.
Or you can just do it with another function:

```
$extension = substr($file_path,strpos($file_path,'.')+1);
```

Comment: Where do i insert this script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$ext=end(explode('.',$file_path))
```